# SSH git commands with username and password

Tags: git, bash, jenkins, ssh

I am running git commands remotely through the SSH protocol as the server doesn't accept HTTPS. I am running it through a bash script and would prefer if I could pass in a username and password as variables.

More specifically, I am doing a migrate of repositories and am having issues when running

```
git remote add origin ssh://${username}:${password}@server.com/repo.git
```

I am running the script through a Jenkins job and am not able to easily prompt for passwords. Is my best option to copy keys to the remote server?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a recent version of Git, you can use the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable:

> ```
>   GIT_SSH, GIT_SSH_COMMAND
>
>       If either of these environment variables is set then git fetch
>       and git push will use the specified command instead of ssh when
>       they need to connect to a remote system. The command will be
>       given exactly two or four arguments: the username@host (or just
>       host) from the URL and the shell command to execute on that
>       remote system, optionally preceded by -p (literally) and the port
>       from the URL when it specifies something other than the default
>       SSH port.
>
>       $GIT_SSH_COMMAND takes precedence over $GIT_SSH, and is
>       interpreted by the shell, which allows additional arguments to be
>       included.  $GIT_SSH on the other hand must be just the path to a
>       program (which can be a wrapper shell script, if additional
>       arguments are needed).
>
>       Usually it is easier to configure any desired options through
>       your personal .ssh/config file. Please consult your ssh
>       documentation for further details.
> ```

So, before you call `git`, you can simply:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /path/to/key'
```

If you can't use an SSH key, you can use the the [Jenkins Credential Binding plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin).

Comment: How would the credentials binding work with GIT_SSH_COMMAND? Or can you just wrap a git command in Jenkins Credentail binding with your ssh key?

Answer (score 1):

1. Another way would be to use the credentials binding plugin. This plugin allows credentials to be bound to environment variables to use from miscellaneous build steps.
2. You could always just login to the remote box and add the Github credentials manually

Cheers

Comment: um, I suggest you re-read the question. OP explicitly said https is not allowed.

Comment: Removed my 1st option. Thanks for catching that